# Unified way of getting list of all destinations for JMS broker

Tags: java, jms

I am working with JMS for quite a long time and was just wondering if there is any way or library that allows you to get all destinations of broker without using classes specific to that broker implementation? (like ActiveMQConnectionFactory and etc)

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JMS 1.0 and 2.0 doesn't have methods for that. As you mentioned, features like that may be in broker-specific APIs, i.e. here is [a link](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-see-what-destinations-are-used.html) for ActiveMQ.
But unfortunately there are no similar methods in JMS API.